# Finding the integral of $x^2 \tan^{-1}x$

Tags: integration

I am given the following integral:

$\int x^2\tan^{-1}x\space dx$

I have tried to solve it the following way, using integration by parts and substitution:

$$\int x^2\tan^{-1}x\space dx = \frac{x^3}{3}\tan^{-1}x - \frac{1}{3}\int\frac{x^3}{1+x^2}\space dx$$

Now, focusing solely on the integral $\frac{1}{3}\int\frac{x^3}{1+x^2}\space dx$:

$u = 1 + x^2 \rightarrow x^2 = u - 1$ and $du = 2x\space dx$, we are left with:

$$\frac{1}{3}\int\frac{\frac{1}{2}du\space(u-1)}{u}\space = \frac{1}{6}\int\frac{\space(u-1)}{u}\space du = \frac{1}{6}(u- \ln |u|) + C$$

Replacing $u$ with $1 + x^2$, we have $\frac{1}{6}((1+x^2)- \ln (1+x^2)) + C$

Thus, the original integral becomes

$$\int x^2\tan^{-1}x\space dx = \frac{x^3}{3}\tan^{-1}x - \frac{1}{6}((1+x^2)- \ln (1+x^2)) + C$$

However, both WolframAlpha and the book represents the answer as:

$$\frac{x^3}{3}\tan^{-1}x - \frac{1}{6}(x^2- \ln (1+x^2)) + C$$

Where did the $1$ go?

Comment: It is just a constant and hence can be included in the $C$.

Comment: It got swallowed up in the integration constant. The derivative of a constant is $0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a term $-1/6$, it is constant that can be assimilated in general constant $C$.